# How to use Push notification in android using JSON protocol?

Tags: android, json, push

I am new to push notification and i dont know how to use it in android. So at first please give me idea about push and then how to use JSON protocol in it.

The app sends PUSH notification to the user via JSON protocol.

Comment: You should give more details, it's hard to tell what you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/ here you go,

but push notifications are android 2.3+ as far as i know...